# Randomize a Number in python with conditions

Tags: python

I have a list made up by these numbers: 3,7,15,31,63.
I need to randomly take one of these numbers, but the one I obtain must be smaller of a Number taken from a cycle (it changes everytime and it is between an interval (10,100).
Can somenone help me please?
P.S. I recently started using python and i don't know a loro about it :)

I don't know how can i do it

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is not clear. Please show us your attempt.

Comment: What do you mean by "must be smaller of a Number taken from a cycle"? If the number is 30, you have to select only from `3, 7, 15`?

Comment: Yeah exactly, if it is 30, i can choose only 3,7,15

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is probably to simply select a random element form the list,

```
import random
r = random.choice([3, 7, 15, 31, 63])
```

and then check if is smaller than the number taken from your cycle.

```
if r < cycle_num:
   print(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import random


lst = [3, 7, 15, 31, 63]

while True: # this is your loop, feel free to change the condition
    n1 = random.randint(10, 100)
    n2 = random.choice([x for x in lst if x < n1])
```

`n2` is your desired random number.